# Return more than one matching record from table into a temp table

Tags: sql, temp-tables, outer-join

I have a query to do with inserting into a temp table. I am finding records from one table where the count > 2 for specific criteria.

**Temp_Table**

```
R1 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
1        1                 2                       1
R2 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
2        2                 2                       2
```

**Table B**

```
R1 - Order ID - ScheduleID
1        1           1
R2 - Order Id - ScheduleID
2        2           2
```

**What I want**

```
R1 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
1        1                 2                       1
R2 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
2        1                 2                       2
R3 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
3        2                 2                       3
R4 - ScheduleID - Count(table b.scheduleid) =2 - orderid
4        2                 2                       4
```

**Code**

```
Update Temp_Table a
right outer join table b
on a.id = b.id
Set orderid=b.id (Here I am setting the column in the temp table = to the matching PK from     tableb
Where (extra conditions go here)
```

The code above shows that I have a temp table that contains the schedule id where the count for this schedule id in table b is > 1. I want to now add into the temp table the order ids from table b that match on the column schedule id.

There is 2 records in table b for every record in the temp table as the count is > 2. The problem i have is that the column i have added to the temp table to show the order ids from table b will only show one of the matching order ids, not both.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?  The syntax looks like MySQL.

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
Update Temp_Table a join
       (select b.id
        from table b
        where (extra conditions go here)
        group by b.id
        having count(*) > 2
       ) b
       on a.id = b.id
    Set newcolumnintemptable = b.id;
```

Some notes:

- If you are updating `a`, then a `right outer join` doesn't make sense.  You need matches in order to do the update.
- This syntax is assuming MySQL.
- If `b.id` is really a primary key, then there will be no matches because such ids are unique.

Comment: Sybase. Thanks, the purpose is to return all records from table b that match the first column id in my temp table. The first column in the temp table is present in both the temp table and table b. The issue I currently have is that my temp table has 50 records and using the join it will show 50 matching records from table B currently but there are 100 matching records as for every record in my temp table there are 2 matching records in Table B.

Comment: @Chris_ . . . As far as I know, the syntax in your question is not correct for Sybase.